# URL Regex doesn't capture all needed cases

Tags: javascript

Hello I made a simple url validation with regex. after doing by using these regex block of code:

```
/(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi;
```

I discovered that I cannot access the form using [www.sitename.com](http://www.sitename.com), but I can access it using https://sitename.com I have tried using so many resouces online to get this fone but all to no avail, how can i access the form using both formats.

Comment: why is your post title all-caps? And why is your post not using SO markdown? You have 31 rep, you _know_ [how to ask a question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Seems to match both those cases : https://regex101.com/r/9iSi6T/1